# Novice to Worlds Without Number: Advice on character creation and motivation

Tags: character-creation, roleplaying, background, worlds-without-number

I got invited to join a role-playing group, who would like to start Worlds Without Number (WWN). The group is familiar with role-playing but for me, this is the very first time ever.

Therefore, I came here, to get advice on **character-building**. As I understand, the game is fun when you play well-aligned character (a true role-play), while the stats/numbers are there to adhere to something tangible to keep the game from spiraling out.

#### Character concept

I would like to exert influence on others, interact with the people, from my party, DM and especially with other people/beings in the story. The influence is there to build/create, not necessarily fight. I don't mind being a support in my party, but I would like to have a plenty of options to change the heading of the party.

#### Short background

My idea is to play a character that has witnessed a lot of pain (either personal or around him) and is driven to change the world to be better place no matter what. For instance, he could be a front-line doctor, who witnessed the devastating effects of war on regular folks while being forced to save the lives of soldiers who bear the responsibility for war. While he was forced to be a front-line doctor, a profession chosen by his priest father, he is educated and had resources to educate himself. Of course, not everything had been according to his fathers liking, and once his father found out he was disinherited. Just another blow to his otherwise kind heart.

As a consequence of the above, he mastered some level of **necromancy** (or communication with spirits) to bring partial relief to the bereaved (by temporarily bringing back the dead or communicating with them). His long-term motivation is to start a religion and spread the thoughts of peace through both clean and unclean/forceful ways (in other words, he is not far from considering becoming a cult leader where "intentions are above the means", although he is not aware of that yet).

His core skills are *convince* and *lead*. Since he has mastered the necromancy, he is not far from being a **mage** (or maybe he is a **full mage** already, since his father may not had been far from magic as well).

The ability to connect with the world of the dead will be used both in fights and also as a "proof" of divine abilities to convince others to join his religion. As a son of a priest (or priest-mage) he understands the religion as a tool but also keeps very close relation to religious symbolism as it seems to be a quite significant part of the WWN.

#### Question

1. What works and doesn't work with the proposed backstory?

#### The best answer

I will probably pick the best answer to be one that puts the character and its abilities into the context of the WWN. At the moment, I have very limited knowledge of WWN, therefore pointing out pitfalls is highly appreciated (e.g. people brought back to life cannot speak, don't remember, etc., such that it breaks the reason to become a necromancer). Advice on how to play and what to seek support from DM for such character (e.g. should I know whether people in the WWN are agnostic?) is appreciated as well.

#### Answers do *not* need to be long

I don't have much time, the quicker the better (I will finish the details on my own with the DM)

Comment: I've edited this question to narrow the scope to a more answerable question based upon the information you've provided. In doing so, I've eliminated your additional questions, which were rather subjective in nature. I'm not familiar with this system, so please review and rollback if doing so is appropriate or these edits have changed your intent.

Answer (score 3):

Best talk to your GM before you solidify your character concept too much -- I've played WWN through a short campaign, and at least in our game, there was no necromancy (or *anything* you'd properly call magic).

You can download the pdf of the core book for free, legitimately, from the game web site; I'd suggest doing that.  Read through the character creation section (the rest is less important, if you're not the GM) so you can see what your options are likely to be.